# Open a WebView after a button pressed with reactNative

Tags: react-native, webview

I am developing a mobile app with React Native. I want to open a WebView after a button pressed. Here is my code, but its not working. The button onPress method is not working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class webView extends Component {

  onNavigationStateChange = navState => {
   if (navState.url.indexOf('https://www.google.com') === 0) {
   const regex = /#access_token=(.+)/;
   const accessToken = navState.url.match(regex)[1];
   console.log(accessToken);
 }
};

renderContent() {
 return (
   <WebView
     source={{
       uri: '',
    }}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
     startInLoadingState
     scalesPageToFit
     javaScriptEnabled
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
   />
 );
}

render() {
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     <Button
       style={styles.paragraph}
       title="Login"
       onPress={() => this.renderContent()}
     />
   </View>
 );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
   backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
 },
});
```

I tried `onPress={this.renderContent()}` this also, but it give an exception. What can I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't rendering your `WebView` in the the render() method of the Component. Just think of render as your DOM of the webpage. You need to provide the component a place in the render component, than you can remove it or add it, see i am calling the `renderContent` from the `render` method. So whenever the state variable `showWebView` is true it will render the `WebView` You should do something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, WebView } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class webView extends Component {

state={
  showWebView: false
}

onNavigationStateChange = navState => {
   if (navState.url.indexOf('https://www.google.com') === 0) {
   const regex = /#access_token=(.+)/;
   const accessToken = navState.url.match(regex)[1];
   console.log(accessToken);
 }
};

renderContent() {
 return (
   <WebView
     source={{
       uri: '',
    }}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
     startInLoadingState
     scalesPageToFit
     javaScriptEnabled
     style={{ flex: 1 }}
   />
 );
}

render() {
 return (
   <View style={styles.container}>
     { this.state.showWebView && this.renderContent() }
     <Button
       style={styles.paragraph}
       title="Login"
       onPress={() => this.setState({showWebView: true})}
     />
   </View>
 );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
   flex: 1,
   alignItems: 'center',
   justifyContent: 'center',
   paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
   backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
 },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must import the following

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview'
```

instead of

```
'react'
```